# Twirl or rotate <DIV> Wrap upon onClick/Submit with CSS3 Animation

Tags: animation, css

I've been trying to figure out a new creative way to show confirmation a message has been sent.  My idea is to actually TWIRL, FLIP or ROTATE the postcard using CSS3 Animation so the frontside appears after the person clicks on submit.  Here is my link:
[link text](http://www.erikrp.com/contact.htm)

I don't want to use flash anymore!!

Anyone can point me in the right direction?  Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Cheers,
Erik

Comment: here is a very good article/tutorial about that, you need a subscription to the site to see it, but there is a preview so you can see if this is waht you are looking for and if want to subscribe or not.  
Here's the link  
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/working-with-advanced-3d-css-new-premium-screencast/

Answer (score 0):

This site has a number of flipping elements:
http://demo.rickyh.co.uk/flipping-crazy-css3/

And this site has some cool flip effects with a decent step-by-step:
http://line25.com/articles/super-cool-css-flip-effect-with-webkit-animation